# How to validate a confirmatory k-means cluster analysis in SPSS?

Tags: clustering, spss, k-means, validation

I've conducted a *k*-means cluster analysis in SPSS using the Z scores of two continuous variables for which the number of clusters was known *a priori* and the total number of observations exceeded 2000. My two questions are as follows:

1) What would be the most straightforward/simple way(s) to validate the clusters in this instance?

2) And what would be necessary to report in the write-up concerning validation?

Please be as specific as possible as I'm a complete novice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is said that there is no significant number of clusters but you may try to check out the elbow method for optimal k. Plus elbow method is not available in spss. If you have sufficient information about the dataset, you can determine the number of clusters yourself.

For validation, you can get the silhouette score by just putting the continuous variables in the twostep cluster tab in the SPSS.